# SAS - percentile from row

Tags: sas, row, percentile

I have a dataset with one base variable and 1000 generated. The base variable is ps_a_pc, the scenarios are called ps_a_var1...ps_a_var1000.

The dataset is as follows:

```
 ps_a_pc ps_a_var1 .... ps_a_var1000
    0       1      ....    5
    3       6      ....   14
```

Now I would like to calculate for each row its minimal value, maximal value and percentiles (20%,40%,60%,80%).

It is easy to get maximal and minimal value:

```
data MinMaxRows;
     set mydata.tot_i;
array x [1000] PS_a_var1-PS_a_var1000;
min = min(of x[*],ps_a_pc);
max = max(of x[*],ps_a_pc);
run;
```

but is there any simple way how to get percentiles for each row ? The only solution coming to my mind is to transpose the dataset and calculate it using univariate function.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PCTL function.

```
data want;
    set have;
    pct80 = pctl(80, of ps_a_var1-ps_a_var1000);
run;
```

Obviously, adjust the '80' value as required for the other percentiles.

Answer (score 1):

Jiri:

Look at the [PCTL() function](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n1m9jbizvp3gwsn1lwf0snogk53i.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).